# Can't pass Core Data object between Swift classes

Tags: core-data, swift3

I have an array of Core Data entities that I can successfully pass from Objective-C VC to a Swift VC. I've verified through the console that they are coming in.

Now I need to loop through the array of core data objects and pass them onto another swift vc. I have the array set up as a property (Customer is the CD entity):

var arrCustomers: Array = Customer

In my loop I am trying to pass them to the other Swift VC:

```
for thisCustomer in self.arrCustomers {

    let gridCell = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "bulkAddCell") as! BulkAddCell
    resizeGridCell(vGridCell: gridCell.view, frameY: frameY, frameH:50.0)

    gridCell.thisCustomer = thisCustomer

    self.svData.addSubview(gridCell.view)
}
```

In BulkAddCell I have thisCustomer as a property:

```
var thisCustomer: Customer!
```

I know BulkAddCell is initializing correctly as I have some IBOutlets in it and I can see them in the console. But thisCustomer is always nil.

I'm making the switch from Obj-C to Swift so I am sure it is something basic I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

**Change:**

```
var arrCustomers: Array = Customer
```

**To:**

```
var arrCustomers = [Customer]() //init to an empty array of customer objects

//sometime later
//append your arrCustomers with instances of Customer

// before leaving first view controller access the arrCustomers object 
// contents as needed and assign to a corresponding property on the 
// destination view controller. (usually in preparforSegue)
```

Comment: I have it set up that way and am still getting nil for customer, am also doing as you said, appending the customer array --> for value in self.arrData {
                    self.arrCustomers.append(value as! Customer)
                }
Also assign the Customer object to the destination controller here: 

gridCell.thisCustomer = thisCustomer

I can see the customer entities in self.arrCustomers, they just don't ever get passed.